llama3 fine tuning data format - shogi
I'm a ML actor, but LLM fintuning are new to me. To train myself, I investigate the possibility to develop a Shogi instructor (japanese chess) based on Llama 3 for example or GPT, to help players to improve their game. I imagine the first step consists in formating specific data coming from shogi pdf, games, or websites for example. But concretely there are standard format for that ? Any tutorial recommandation ?
